# Showing that a series that involves Legendre polynomial converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series, legendre-polynomials

I am currently studying Legendre polynomials and I am trying to prove its generating function **specifically** using the recurrence relation

$$ (n+1)L_{n+1}(x) = x(2n+1)L_n(x) - nL_{n-1}(x), \quad \forall n\geqslant 0.$$
where $L_n(x)$ represents the $n-$order Legendre polynomial. I have searched quite some places to find a proof like this but wasn't able to find something concrete on it. Most of the proofs I saw of the generating function make use of the binomial theorem.

With this in mind, I believe I am doing a good work so far. With some easy calculation, one can easily check that the recurrence relation presented above yields

$$ xL_n(x)  - L_{n-1}(x) = (n+1)L_{n+1}(x) - 2xnL_n(x) + (n-1)L_{n-1}(x), \quad \forall n \geqslant 0.$$

Now, I was wondering: It would be really cool if we could just guarantee something like this *(for some $w?$)*:

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} w^n (xL_n(x) - L_{n-1}(x)) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}w^n\Big[(n+1)L_{n+1}(x) -2xnL_n(x) + (n-1)L_{n-1}(x)\Big].$$
As a matter fact, assuming convergence of both series, I was able to prove the generating function based off this result. Thus, what is left to do now is to show that we can actually assume this convergence.

**First thing first.** It suffices to show that one of the series converge, since by the second recurrence relation above these two series are exactly the same thing.

**Second things second.** Let us now try to show convergence of one of the series: for example, let us grab the L.H.S. First, we study the series

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x L_n(x)w^n \quad \text{ and } \quad \sum_{n=0}^\infty L_{n-1}(x)w^n.$$

Note that

$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty x L_n(x)w^n = x \sum_{n=0}^\infty L_n(x)w^n = x(1+xw+\frac{1}{2}(3x^2-1)w^2+\dots), $$
which clearly represents a geometric series with a non-constant coefficient. How can one show that such series converges?

I would be really gratefull for hints.

Comment: It is a **formal series**, therefore we shouldn't be bothered by its convergence.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks for your feedback. I haven't heard about **formal series** before. What do you exactly mean by we shouldn't be bothered by its convergence? Formal series always converge for every values of $w$ and every sequence of coefficients?

Comment: It is precisely what I mean by "not been bothered" : they are always meaningful...

Comment: @JeanMarie Oh wow... I guess I've just learnt something new today. Seems quite a strong concept though! Thanks for your help! Perhaps you want to elaborate an aswer :)

Comment: No, I will not elaborate an answer... So many well-written documents exist on this subject, for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Regard $x$ as a parameter. You can quickly determine the radius $R$ of convergence of the series $\sum_k L_k w^k$ by using the ratio test, which involves estimating the limiting behavior of $|L_n/L_{n+1}|\to R$.
From the recurrence equation, after dividing everything by the LHS and taking limits you get a quadratic equation that $R$ must satisfy.